# How to aggregate and groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following df,I'd like to group by`customer` and then,`count`and`sum`

at the same time,I wish add conditional grouping.

are there any way to achieve this?

```
customer  product score
A          a       1
A          b       2
A          c       3
B          a       4
B          a       5
B          b       6
```

My desired result is following

```
customer count sum count(product =a)  sum(product=a)
A          3    6     1                   1
B          3   15     2                   9
```

My work is like this..

`grouped=df.groupby('customer')`

`grouped.agg({"product":"count","score":"sum"})`

Thanks

Comment: filter the dataframe, then group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try `crosstab`

```
s = pd.crosstab(df['customer'],df['product'], df['score'],margins=True, aggfunc=['sum','count']).drop('All')
Out[76]: 
          sum               count              
product     a    b    c All     a    b    c All
customer                                       
A         1.0  2.0  3.0   6   1.0  1.0  1.0   3
B         9.0  6.0  NaN  15   2.0  1.0  NaN   3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'customer': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'product': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b'], 'score':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
df = df[df['product']=='a']
grouped=df.groupby('customer')
grouped = grouped.agg({"product":"count","score":"sum"}).reset_index()
print(grouped)
```

Output:

```
  customer  product  score
0        A        1      1
1        B        2      9
```

Then merge this dataframe with the unfiltered grouped dataframe